# Intersection of n hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality, affine-geometry

For all unit vector $\nu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ consider an affine hyperplane $A_{\nu}$ orthogonal to the direction $\nu $.

Now consider n linearly independent unit vectors $\nu_ 1 , \nu_2, \dots, \nu_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I'm asking: is the intersection $A_{\nu_1} , A_{\nu_2}, \dots , A_{\nu_n}$ necessarily a point?

I think the answer is yes, but I'm not sure... In the case $n =2$ it is true (the intersection of two lines having different directions is a point). In the case $n=3$ is also true. But in general is it true?

Comment: When you say that $A_{\nu}$ is an affine hyperplane you must also specify a point on the plane.  This does not change the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Eric. But I don't understand: am I wrong If I say "Consider an affine hyperplane $A_{\nu}$ orthogonal to $\nu$" even if I mean that we don't have information about the point but we only know that it is orthogonal to $\nu$? I hope my question is clear

Comment: Any plane parallel to the plane you are thinking of is orthogonal to $\nu$.  How about the perpendicular bisector of $\nu$?  How about the linear subspace perpendicular to $\nu$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is just a point. It is a solution of a system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\langle\nu_1,x\rangle=\mu_1\\\langle\nu_2,x\rangle=\mu_2\\\vdots\\\langle\nu_n,x\rangle=\mu_n.\end{array}\right.$$This is a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns and the fact that the $\nu_k$'s are linearly independent is equivalent to the assertion that the matrix of its coefficients is invertible. Therefore, the system has one and only one solution.

Comment: Is it really $\mu_i$? or 0?

Comment: It would be zero if we were working with hyperplanes *passing through the origin*, but the OP wasn't assuming that.

Comment: Ah correct, thank you for the reminder!